# What's the fastest way to only rotate certain elements in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, rotation

I'm writing a form of word scrambler for strings which takes all letters except for the first and last, and rotates their positions. However, I am supposed to only look at the second to second last letters. How should I only scramble from the second last letter to the second last letter?

e.g. scramble "string" to "srintg"

I can call Collections.rotate() on an array of characters created by splitting the string, but that will scramble the entire word.

```
List<String> newWordList = Arrays.asList(word.split(" "));
Collections.rotate(newWordList, -1);
String newWord = String.join("", newWordList);
```

I want to get the output "srintg", but instead I will get "rintgs".

Comment: What do you mean by the 'fastest way'? Do you have a very large data set, or is this for a challenge?

Comment: Do you only want to rotate the 2nd and 2nd-last? Or all except the 1st and last? _"takes all letters except for the first and last"_, "_only look at the second to second last letters_"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that your word is long enough for it to be sensible (at least four letters), you can make the approach you present work by rotating a sublist of your list:

```
Collections.rotate(newWordList.subList(1, newWordList.size() - 1), -1);
```

`List.subList()` creates a view of a portion of a `List` list for the exact purpose of avoiding the need for overloading `List` methods with versions that operate on indexed sub-ranges of the elements.  That's "fast" in the sense of fast to write, and it's fairly clear.

If you are looking for "fast" in a performance sense, however, then splitting and joining strings seems ill-advised.  Fast*est* is probably not something we can offer, as performance needs to be tested, but if I were looking for best performance then I would test at least these general approaches:

- Work with an array form of your word

  1. Use `String.toCharArray()` to obtain your word's letters in array form.
  2. Use an indexed `for` loop to rotate the characters in the array.
  3. Construct a new `String` from the modified array (using the appropriate constructor).
- Use a `StringBuilder` to assemble the word

  1. Create a `StringBuilder` with initial capacity equal to the word length.
  2. Iterate over the word's letters using a `CharacterIterator`, appending them to the builder in the order required.  This can be done in a single pass.
  3. Obtain the result string from the builder.